# Jenkins Git plugin - 401

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I've tried all sort of different things and I can't get jenkins to play nice with git.

I have setup my ssh keys and verified that I can ssh to the git hub and I get the message.
I also, have tried w/o the .git extention. I've tried with user name in the url, user name and password in the url, and no username/passsord at all. Fails to matter waht.

I've also tried it with an admin user and a plain push/pull user.

The git repository I'm trying to hit is through an "organization" but I'm on a team that has access.

```
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone https://github.com/xxx/xx
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone https://github.com/xxx/xx
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:245)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1073)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1014)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:788)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:770)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1014)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1195)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:579)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:468)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1408)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:478)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git clone --progress -o origin https://github.com/xxxx/xx /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
Command "git clone --progress -o origin https://github.com/xxxx/xx /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace" returned status code 128: Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://github.com/xxxx/xx/info/refs
```

Comment: yes it is a private repo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the r/w address for cloning private repos using ssh keys:

`git@github.com:xxx/xx.git`

Comment: That works perfectly. I'm not at 15 yet so I can't bump up the answer.

Comment: Now you are ;) May you also mark the answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the credentials on the URL, make sure they're URL encoded. Also make sure you're using Basic authentication.

Comment: Yeah.. I didn't have any characters in there that would have required encoding. The weird thing is that I can't even run that command from the command line. I can push/pull from the command line on my dev box. I can push and pull just fine, but if I run that clone command it blows up.